# Converting a single GPS point in xy coordinate to latitude and longitude

Tags: mapinfo

I picked a GPS point for a Helipad using the AGD 66 Zone 55 Datum, however have been asked by the chopper pilot to give him coordinates in the Latitude and Longitude format so he can land the chopper for an emergency case and I was'nt able to do that. To avoid such issues in the future, could someone help me convert this. I use MapInfo Encom Discover 2013.

Answer (score 1):

AGD 66 Zone 55 Datum is a projected UTM coordinate system.
The geographic spheroid for this datum is Australian_1966.

Normally helicopters will use WGS-84 datum read from the GPS sensors.
The format they would prefer would be decimal minutes.
i.e. Lat dd mm.mmm S Long ddd mm.mmm E where dd is degrees mm.mmm is decimal minutes

You will need to set your map document to WGS-84 datum.
I'm an Arcmap user and we do this by setting the coordinate system of the data frame to the required spatial system (i.e. and GCS_WGS_1984).

You will then need to select the transformation parameters that convert from  Australian_1966 to GCS_WGS_1984. There are probably many predefined transformations to choose from and since its for the helicopter pilots you could select any of them. (i.e. the coordinate should only need to be accurate to the nearest 5-10m)

Once the map document is set to GCS_WGS_1984 datum the curser should display geographic coordinates in latitude and longitude.

Hope this helps.